# Как получить значения полей в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Использую библиотеку для диалоговых окон SweetAlert2 https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Мой код, где пользователь вводит значения в поля:

```
swal({
      title: '<h2>' + add_alb_title  + '</h2>',
      type: 'info',
      html:
        '<div class="swal_title">' + album_title + '</div><input type="text" value="" class="album_title" name="album_title" maxlength="30" /><br />' +
        '<div class="swal_title">' + album_description + '</div><textarea name="album_description" class="album_description" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="125" ></textarea><br />' +
        '',
      showCloseButton: true,
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: button_add,
      cancelButtonText: button_cancel
    }).then(function (result) {
    // Здесь нужно получить значения из полей, чтобы отправить их в ajax
    // В result просто true
      swal(
        'Created!',
        'Your album has been created.' + JSON.stringify(result),
        'success'
      )
    });
```

Подскажите, как получить значения input и textarea?

Answer (score 2):

В `then()` это делать поздно, т.к. модальное окно там уже закрыто и его контент потерян.

`preConfirm()`- правильное место для того, чтобы получить значения кастомных полей ввода. Также, советую использовать документированный метод `swal.getContent()` для получения содержимого:

```js
Swal.fire({
  html:
    '<input name="album_title"><br>' +
    '<textarea name="album_description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>',
  preConfirm: () => {
    var album_title = swal.getContent().querySelector('[name=album_title]').value
    var album_description = swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('[name=album_description]').value
    
    console.log(album_title, album_description)
    
    // тут делаешь AJAX запрос
  },
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```